# SASS error import 'variables'. SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am facing a certain problem. I was trying to send the `html` and `CSS` documents into my react project. The problem is

```
    ./src/scss/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/scss/app.scss)
    SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
      ╷
    1 │ @import 'variables';
      │         ^^^^^^^^^^^
      ╵
      src\scss\components\_header.scss 1:9  @import
      src\scss\components\_all.scss 1:9     @import
      src\scss\app.scss 5:9                 root stylesheet
```

[Original Error Image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHOtl.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should import it with the complete path and the extension of the file. For example:

`@import './variables.scss';`

If you are using create-react-app or node you might want to check if you have `node-sass` installed. More info here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: Thanks for the respond. I've done this but it does no sense. It gives the same error. Could you please look at the picture I added in a post and write the proper @import?

Comment: node-sass is installed

Comment: try `@import './_variables.scss';`

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

I added an answer below that is probably unrelated to your use case, but as I started looking at your screenshot more it looks like your file is named `_variables.scss` which is a partial and is imported with the `@use` rule. Can you try `@use "variables";`? https://sass-lang.com/guide

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

I experienced this issue running Storybook with Nx and sass-loader:

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../../node_modules/@nrwl/web/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "variables";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Changing to a relative import worked, but I had `@import "variables"` all over my code and didn't want to have to change to `@import "../../../styles/variables.scss"` everywhere. I was finally able to resolve it by adding an alias to the webpack config via `webpackFinal` in `.storybook/main.js`:

```
// .storybook/main.js

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      'variables': path.resolve(__dirname, '../styles/variables.scss')
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

versions used:

```
"@nrwl/cli": "13.2.3"
"@nrwl/storybook": "13.2.3"
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.3.0"
"@storybook/builder-webpack5": "6.3.0"
"@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.3.0"
"@storybook/react": "6.3.0"
"sass-loader": "13.0.0"
```

webpack resolve alias documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias